# How do I summon a villager that only makes noise when hit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I summon villagers that make noise only when taking damage? In other words I don't want to hear their idle noises, but I also don't want a completely silent villager. How do I do this in Minecraft version 1.10?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this is to make a resource pack, with the villager sounds being sound files that have no audio.  Another option is to add the `Silent` tag, and then use `/playsound` to play a hurt sound effect.

Answer (score -3):

Copy and paste this command into Minecraft

/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Silent:1}

Comment: There's a difference between 'making pian noises' and 'muted'.